# Arguments that are dependent on other arguments with Argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I want to accomplish something like this:

```
-LoadFiles
    -SourceFile "" -DestPath ""
    -SourceFolder "" -DestPath ""
-GenericOperation
    -SpecificOperation -Arga "" -Argb ""
    -OtherOperation -Argc "" -Argb "" -Argc ""
```

A user should be able to run things like:

```
-LoadFiles -SourceFile "somePath" -DestPath "somePath"
```

or

```
-LoadFiles -SourceFolder "somePath" -DestPath "somePath"
```

Basically, if you have `-LoadFiles`, you are required to have either `-SourceFile` or `-SourceFolder` after. If you have `-SourceFile`, you are required to have `-DestPath`, etc.

Is this chain of required arguments for other arguments possible? If not, can I at least do something like, if you have `-SourceFile`, you MUST have `-DestPath`?

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue11588 explores ways of adding general interdependency tests, but until that is implemented, your best bet is to do the testing yourself, after parsing.

Comment: This is what _sub-commands_ are for. See [`ArgumentParser.add_subparsers()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After you call `parse_args` on the `ArgumentParser` instance you've created, it'll give you a `Namespace` object.  Simply check that if one of the arguments is present then the other one has to be there too.  Like:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
if ('LoadFiles' in vars(args) and 
    'SourceFolder' not in vars(args) and 
    'SourceFile' not in vars(args)):

    parser.error('The -LoadFiles argument requires the -SourceFolder or -SourceFile')
```

Comment: I guess @Feuermurmel means this answer needs improvement.

Comment: I prefer @saeed-gharedaghi's answer.

Comment: While this works, it is not flexible if additional options are added, @saeed-gharedaghi's answer allows for that

Answer (score 53):

You can use subparsers in argparse

```
 import argparse
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
 parser.add_argument('--foo', required=True, help='foo help')
 subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')

 # create the parser for the "bar" command
 parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('bar', help='a help')
 parser_a.add_argument('bar', type=int, help='bar help')
 print(parser.parse_args())
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample that in case you specify --makeDependency, forces you to specify --dependency with a value as well.

This is not done by argparse alone, but also by by the program that later on validates what the user specified.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--makeDependency', help='create dependency on --dependency', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--dependency', help='dependency example')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.makeDependency and not args.dependency:
    print "error on dependency"
    sys.exit(1)

print "ok!"
```

Comment: Best practice to write error message to stderr
sys.stderr.write('error on dependency')

Answer (score 3):

There are some `argparse` alternatives which you can easily manage cases like what you mentioned.
packages like:
[click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) or
[docopt](http://docopt.org/).

If we want to get around the manual implementation of chain arguments in argparse, check out the [Commands and Groups](http://click.pocoo.org/5/commands/) in click for instance.