# argparse: argument names that depend on the value(s) of another argument?

Tags: python, argparse

e.g., to parse

`./test.py --species electron proton --mass_electron 1`

Here, the second argument name `mass_electron` is valid because `electron` is one of the values we passed to the argument `species`.

**Edit 1**:

This is different from another question [Arguments that are dependent on other arguments with Argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411268/arguments-that-are-dependent-on-other-arguments-with-argparse)
since I would like the argument name to depend on the ***value*** of another argument, i.e., that value is arbitrary.

Comment: Most cross checking is best done after parsing - when all of the inputs are known, regardless of their order in the commandline.   The only mechanisms that `argparse` provides are the subparsers and mutually exclusive groups (xor).  (Some people have tried custom `Action` classes, or multistage parsing, but the resulting code is usually more complicated.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper way is not to perform dynamic feeding of argument types to argparse, but to declare **all possible** arguments, parse command line and then raise exception if their combination is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I ended up specifying all possible arguments, though some are fake placeholders if I don't truly need them. Dynamic feeding does cause confusion. The problem comes from the fact that some of the information is not contained in the data file, i.e., I made the assumptions depending on additional information.