# Argparse custom 'store_true' action with a check

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like to check if `action='store_true` dependent script arguments were provided. For example,

```
run.py --save_files --out_dir "saved_files" --files_to_save 10
```

Such that whenever `run.py --save_files` is called without `--out_dir` or `--files_to_save`, it fails and shows an error message.

I am trying to do it the following way:

```
class CheckedStoreTrue(argparse._StoreTrueAction):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if not namespace.out_dir:
            parser.error("Please provide an output dir!")
        if not namespace.files_to_save:
            parser.error("Please provide a number of files to save!")
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)
```

then in

```
prs.add_argument(
    "--save_files",
    action=CheckedStoreTrue,
    required=False,
    help="Save files.",
)
```

This does not work and keeps throwing `Please provide an output dir!` even after I provide the `out_dir` parameter. If I check the `namespace` content, I see `out_dir=None`. I wonder why?

Comment: Why create an action? Why not just check the condition after parsing the arguments? Just like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411268/arguments-that-are-dependent-on-other-arguments-with-argparse

Comment: A subcommand would probably be more suitable: `run.py save_files --out_dir "saved_files" --files_to_save 10`, with the options being marked as required (though I would then prefer a simple pair of positional arguments instead of options).

Comment: slap! stupid me

Comment: Arguments are processed in the order given in `sys.argv`.  `--save_files` is first, so your `CheckedStoreTrue` runs before any `out_dir` values (other than default) have been put in the `namespace`.  It might run as intended if put last.  Interdependencies that depend on the order of arguments are best implemented after parsing, as opposed to during.